# How to do garbage collection(or release collection) in vty-ui

Tags: haskell

I'm learning the [vty-ui](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vty-ui) library. For the following code segment:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  coll <- newCollection
  (ui1, fg1) <- mkFirstUI

  switchToFirst <- addToCollection coll ui1 fg1
```

My question is: how to delete the `switchToFirst` ? My program needs to constantly create similar object of the `switchToFirst` type and I don't want to keep them in memory once used. But in the `vty-ui` library I can't find a release function.

Comment: What makes you think you have to explicitly delete or release it?

Comment: You mean GHC will do it for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than triggering a garbage collection, which GHC does when needed, and you can force it with

[`System.Mem.performGC`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Mem.html)

you may prevent the task from growing unlimitedly by capping the heap max size with

+RTS -Msize

as listed in the users guide [RTS options to control the garbage collector](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html#rts-options-gc)

Check this [GHC advice area](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/sooner-faster-quicker.html) for improving memory efficiency.